# Broken Tub Faucet pipe

Tags: plumbing, shower

[image]Ok so I played plumber on our master bath trying to update the fixtures but old was corroded and when I tried to unscrew it the copper pipe piece twisted off and broke. So…my question is the shower/tub is a bath tub with 3 panels of acrylic. One of the panels is where the tub faucet is. Is it possible to remove the panel without damaging it so I can have someone repair the pipe and reuse the panel or am I looking at a new shower surround?
[image]
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to repair that is from the other side of the wall.

Notice there was nothing too unscrew since it was soldered and in your defense you did not know and applied to much force to rip it apart.

If you work from other side, the panels can stay in place.

Only thing you have to do is to close the new drywall hole and replace the insulation inside after fixing the plumbing.

Comment: Fantastic thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Usually it's easier to go in from the **other** side of the wall. A good shower installation will have an access panel there. You can cut a hole for access and make your installation good by putting an access panel over it when the repair is complete.

Removing the shower panel without damage may be possible, but it may be brittle with age, as plastics get, and break when you attempt to remove it.